# How to find which Future caused "Future exception was never retrieved"

Tags: python, python-asyncio

```
[15:29:19] Future exception was never retrieved
future: <Future finished exception=ConnectionError('Connection to Telegram failed 1 time(s)')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/project/file.py", line 72, in _connect
    await client.connect()
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/project/resources/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telethon/client/telegrambaseclient.py", line 551, in connect
    LAYER, self._init_request
ConnectionError: Connection to Telegram failed 1 time(s)
```

How can I find the exact Future object whose exception was never retrieved? I can only see the exact exception and some stacktrace (from which I cannot find the Future itself). It would be great, if I could know where that Future has been defined in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enabling the debug mode reveals where the Future has been created.
https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/asyncio-dev.html#debug-mode